# Does anyone have any information about the sequel to "Fleet Elements"?

Tags: praxis-universe

*Fleet Elements* (2020) is the second book in Walter Jon Williams' *The Second Books of the Praxis* trilogy.  When it was first listed (but before its release date), there was also a third book in the trilogy listed with a 2021 release date.

I don't even recall the title that was given in the listing; I never expected I'd need to *remember* it, but now I can't find a single reference to it anywhere.  At this point it's obviously not going to be released in 2021, but there isn't even a listing for a 2022 release.

Does anyone know what's happening with it?  When it will be released?  Even the title?

(For example, the only forthcoming book by WJW that [Locus has listed](https://locusmag.com/forthcomingbooks/) is *Lord Quillifer*.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per his blog on Goodreads, it's currently with the editors.

> I’ve delivered the next Praxis book to my editor at Harper, so yay. It
> doesn’t have an official title yet because that’s still under
> discussion. (Right now I’m calling it “The Nameless.”) Nor does it
> have a publication date, though I’m guessing it might appear around
> this time next year.
>
> It will start right where Fleet Elements ended and continue from
> there.
>
> You are at liberty to start salivating now.
>
> <sub><sup>[The Praxis Eternal - goodreads: October 26, 2021 21:33](https://www.goodreads.com/author_blog_posts/21861684-the-praxis-eternal)</sup></sub>

Comment: Ah, thank you!  I didn't know he had a blog there; his personal website is years out of date.  Bookmarked.

Answer (score 3):

According to a [recent blog post](http://www.walterjonwilliams.net/2022/01/eye-catching/), the sequel to *Fleet Elements* will be *Imperium Restored*, which is currently scheduled for September 2022.

> Behold a proposed cover for the next Praxis book, **launching next September.** This isn’t the final cover, so the published version might be somewhat different.

[image: Cover of "Imperium Restored" showing many small ships attacking 3 huge ships in orbit around a planet]